# Difference between may be and can be while replying to my superior officer

Tags: word-usage

When I am telling my boss to do some thing which word is appropriate:

You *can* close the purchase activity.

or

You *may* close the purchase activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both words can basically be used interchangeably through speech/writing.  May is perceived as asking for permission in a polite way, but that isn't how the two are used.  No matter how many times a teacher corrects her students they will still say 'Can I go to the bathroom?'

We can debate what should be said in these cases but the fact that 'can' is used so often really waters down the pro-may rants.

Now in your case (talking to a boss/superior) I will make three observations:

- I would try to limit the use of either of these.  If A and B need to be done for the purchase activity to be closed.  I would say 'B is complete' or 'the purchase activity can be closed'.
- If I had to take one of the two sentences I would say 'can' because may sounds like you are the boss.
- I would just use whatever wording your superior wants.  If he/she has a preference I would go with that.  Neither are wrong to say.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between can and may is essentially between expressing capability ( can) or permission (may). But the issue is not so clear-cut.  I add the following link for reference:

[Can or may?](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/can-or-may)

*People are often uncertain about whether there is any difference between can and may when these verbs are used to ask for or grant permission.* For example, is one of these two sentences ‘more correct’ than the other?

Can I ask you a few questions?

May I ask you a few questions?

There is a widespread view that using can to ask for permission is wrong and that it should only be used in expressions to do with ability or capability, e.g.:

Can she swim?

Can you speak Italian?

*But the 'permission' use of can is not in fact incorrect in standard English.* The only difference between the two verbs is that one is more polite than the other. In informal contexts it’s perfectly acceptable to use can; in formal situations it would be better to use may.

Answer (score 0):

The use of 'may' indicates you are giving permission for the action, and 'can' just indicates the action,  or closing off the purchase activity is possible

Comment: Certainly that's the traditional distinction. However, in daily spoken usage, many people habitually use "you can" (i.e. *you have permission to*) where you might use "you may". It's partly a question of the register and degree of formality of the context.